# Highcharts, How to show datatable when export PDF and not show pdf when normal with Drilldown Chart

Tags: highcharts

Highcharts, How to show datatable when export PDF and not show pdf when normal with Drilldown Chart.
I want to export PDF or PNG file with Drilldown-Chart, But it's not work because I set

```
xAxis: {
            type: 'category'
        },
```

I don't know. How should be set xAxis.
Before I can set xAxis because I do regular charts such as Basic column, Basic bar chart and etc.
And before I using method

```
events: {
                load(){
                    if(this.renderer.export){
                        Highcharts.drawTable(this);
                    }
                }
            },
```

For to hide data-table But it's can't work with drilldown charts

Comment: Please reproduce your issue on some online editor with the sample data.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/teeraphongsing/kpxs5jrd/17/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Notice that in the demo that you have shared the drawTable function should take the chart as an argument and `var chart = this` assignment breaks the function working.

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/dre9j6nw/